# jMeter - How to reset a Counter

Tags: loops, jmeter, controller, counter

I would like to know how to reset a Counter that is inside a Loop Controller nested into another Loop Controller, please see the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1znA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjLCQ.png)

I need only to reset to 1 the second Counter ("response Counter").
Thanks everyone !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) code:

```
def engine = ctx.getEngine();
def test = engine.getClass().getDeclaredField("test");
test.setAccessible(true);

def testPlanTree = test.get(engine);
def counterSearch = new org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass<>(org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.CounterConfig.class)
testPlanTree.traverse(counterSearch)
def counter = counterSearch.getSearchResults().first()
counter.globalCounter = 1 //or whatever your desired value here
```

However I don't think you need to use Counter at all because:

- [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) exposes the current iteration number
- It also seems that you can replace the whole construction with the [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)